# How to create a list of words from a list of sentences

Tags: python

a = ['Hi How are you', 'i am doing fine', 'how about you']

Here a is a list of sentences. I need something like this using python.

result = [Hi How are you i am doing fine how about you]

Comment: `[' '.join(a)]`

Comment: I think one of the edits changed the meaning of the question completely. I rolled it back to its initial state. @VivekWilliam, the line `result = [Hi How are you i am doing fine how about you]` is not a valid Python, so it's unclear what result you really expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) - method takes input iterable like list, string, etc. and return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable.

```
>>> [' '.join(a)]
['Hi How are you i am doing fine how about you']
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code does this:

`result = " ".join(a)`

Comment: As they asked for a list, this should technically be `result = [" ".join(a)]`

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to split the sentences further like the title suggests:

```
a = ['Hi How are you', 'i am doing fine', 'how about you']
words = [w for x in a for w in x.split()]
print(words)
```

Gives:

```
['Hi', 'How', 'are', 'you', 'i', 'am', 'doing', 'fine', 'how', 'about', 'you']
```

Using a nested list-comprehension